# Google Captcha ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key on loadbalancer and unable to send out email

Tags: smtp, load-balancing, captcha

I got some problems that I have been stuck with for almost 1 week now. it's about this error google captcha site key

and cant send out emails from the load balancer.

the network topology is this the 3 webserver is on 1 load balancer IP address...
when I'm using the load balancer as an IP address at my DNS the error came out saying this

Google Captcha ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key

and cant send out an email from the load balancer IP saying this error

{"status":"error","time":0.0,"flags":{},"data":{"code":"UnauthenticatedFromAddress","message":"The From address is not authorised to send mail from this server"}}

what should I do guys tell me is this something with the SSL? or the firewall rule on the load balancer?

I'm so fascinated that I know this technology becos my business is cloud-based I can't afford downtime it costs me a lot and losing clients.

I'm willing to give someone who can solve this a gift from my heart with some dollar donation for helping me.

picture of the error: https://prnt.sc/0MWuFC5Yioif

Answer (score 0):

I already figure it out, all you need to do is install your domain SSL key like my case I'm using Cloudflare.

first, you need to generate the CSR and then paste the CSR at Cloudflare, and Cloudflare will give you a .pem file and save it as a key.pem and go back to your platform copy the private key save it as SSL.key

after that import that SSL into your platform and install it on your domain.
the error key from google ReCaptcha will solved the same as the sender email from load balancer just make it authorized with the SSL all should be good